# How can change my field to hold an array of objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb to store the data.

I have a field "campus" to hold the ObjectIds of Campus data.

Intially the user had a single campus, but later on the type of campus had to be modified to hold an array of campus. But the initial records remained to be the same.

Now while I'm trying to push a new campusId, some records are not updating because of type change.

I have some 500 records in which some records have single objectId and in some records the campus is an array of ObjectIds.

Like this,

"campusIds" : ObjectId("5c8f304a4350a990f7c40")

And,

```
"campusIds" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d136de2a02b2c14947652"), 
        ObjectId("5d136f0da02b2c14947656"), 
        ObjectId("5d137082a02b2c14947658"), 
        ObjectId("5d14520da02b2c1494765c"), 
        ObjectId("5d1459dd81801aef0865a8") ]
```

I cannot manaully change the records in mongodb as the records in large number.

Is there a way I can change the field to an array in my db?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for a list of ids to be called `campusIds`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a query which only filters documents where the field exists and it's of ObjectId type ([`$type 7`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)). The results from this query can then be used to do a bulk update on the collection.
The following async operation does the above:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const docs = await db.collection('collectionName').find({
            'campus': {
                '$exists': true, 
                '$type': 7 
            }
        }).toArray()

        const ops = docs.map(({ _id, campus }) => ({
            'updateOne': { 
                'filter': { _id } ,              
                'update': { '$set': { 'campusIds': [campus] } } 
            } 
        }))

        db.collection('collectionName').bulkWrite(ops)
    } catch(err) {
        // handle error
    }
})()
```

Comment: Even if the campusId has muliple ids, type will be still object and not array

Comment: The query `{
            'campus': {
                '$exists': true, 
                '$type': 7 
            }
        }` returns all documents in the collection where the field `campus` exists AND is an `ObjectId`